# Where in my CSS is this background colour set?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors, background-color

As you can see on my website [Trolleyy.com](http://trolleyy.com) I am trying to copy a theme button's style for my email form from the Go to shop button. The issue is I as much as I have tried to copy the css from inspecting it, it still looks completely different. I tried to add an !important rule of no background but this removed the boarder too.

Does anyone know how to either:

A) Copy the whole css style of that button or

B) Know how I can change the button from a grey to transparent background

As is probably obvious I am learning how to style in CSS and this would really help me! I have been playing with different idea's for hours. Thanks.

Comment: Add the CSS you have right now and try to replicate the environment so we can modify it on JSFiddle or codepen...

Comment: Did you try adding `background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);` to `<a href="/shop-four-column/" target="_self" class="mk-button custom button-56984cf6e087c light outline-dimension large pointed "><span>GO TO SHOP.
</span></a>`

Comment: You can always try `Inspect Element` and browse the `Computed Style` section.

Comment: pls show the css that you want to add for the button.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are two very different elements.  One is an `input type=submit` and the other is an `anchor`.  This means that just copying the CSS classes might not work due to other complex rules associated with the specific elements.

Upon inspection of your site, it looks like you'll need to define some rules for either `input#mc-embedded-subscribe.button` or update the rules in `#optin input[type="submit"]`.  I just played around with the first one and was able to turn the button red.  Something in your CSS stack is also turning off the border with an `!important`, so the only way to get a border on the button is to re-apply the border settings also with an `!important.`

I made this rule and got the button to match the Go To Shop button:

```
input#mc-embedded-subscribe.button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff !important;
}
```

The complexity of your CSS makes it difficult to provide a more general-purpose solution, although, one probably does exist.

A general recommendation is to avoid using the `!important` modifier too much, because it can make debugging the CSS very difficult.  If too many things are important, then none of them really are.

Comment: "This goes against the very nature of CSS. While this suggested approach will probably produce the desired results, the CSS is cumbersome and very specific"

Comment: @WilliamCallahan Very unprofessional of you to quote my comment without giving attribution (and now that your answer is deleted, no one will ever know that they are not your words).  Further unprofessional of you to leave this comment as a way to "get back at me" because your answer received multiple down votes.  I at least provided the feedback for the down vote, while others did not.  In fact, you have no idea if I was actually one of the down voters.  Regardless, if you're focusing on the points, I think you're missing the true purpose of SO.

Comment: Yes, the answer had unnecessary definitions, however, it was still correct. Also, I understand the purpose of Stack Overflow, however, people with lower reputations will tend to want to build their reputation. This does not make it right, but it is just hat happens. While my response may have been unprofessional (yes, sorry for that), if people post hypocritical or invalid comments, it can get annoying. Anyways, here's your up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your CSS :

```
#mc-embedded-subscribe {
    background: transparent;
    border-width: 2px!important;
    border-style: solid!important;
}


#mc-embedded-subscribe:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
```

After adding that code, your form should look something like this :

[image]

Comment: @WilliamCallahan : The minified CSS file of the theme he's using is a 328kb bloated mess (http://trolleyy.com/wp-content/themes/jupiter/stylesheet/css/theme-styles.min-blessed1.css?z=1421777842642). The perfect solution would be to remove all the bloat, redesign the CSS architecture, improve the HTML, etc. This could take days, even for a CSS expert. I went with a solution that may not be perfect, but that at least takes less than a minute to apply.

Comment: @WilliamCallahan Your post was about a dozen lines of CSS applying multiple styles that may or may not have been necessary, and suggested that they be applied directly to the element (before your edit).  This answer (and my answer) are very few lines that fit carefully into the bloated complexity of the OP's theme template.  Sorry that you feel bad about losing points - mine was not the only down vote.  SO is not about the points - it's about providing the most appropriate, thoughtful answers.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following on the "SUBSCRIBE" button:

```
.button-clear {
    background-color: transparent;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-style: solid !important;
    border-width: 2px !important;
    border-image-outset: 0px !important;
    border-image-repeat: stretch !important;
    border-image-slice: 100% !important;
    border-image-source: none !important;
    border-image-width: 1 !important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
}

.button-clear:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
    color: #333333 !important;
}
```

Please Note: I highly advise trying to avoid using `!important`

Comment: This goes against the very nature of CSS.  If everything is important, then nothing really is.  While this suggested approach will probably produce the desired results, the CSS is cumbersome and *very* specific.

Comment: I was just trying to get the first post. I would never actually do that. Also, the website has several `!important` definitions defined already. This may require the use of `!important`. Take a look at the hover state of the "Go Shop" button, for example. It was done incorrectly from the start.

Comment: Being the first is rarely the most desirable goal.  It's better to provide more appropriate answers than rush things.

Comment: Well, the current edit is fairly correct due to the fact that the creator of the template used so many `important` from the start. You cannot avoid this. You know this given that your example has it too.